# Beamer "Presentation Mode" for Offline File (Overleaf Editor)

Tags: beamer, pdf, overleaf

I've made a Beamer presentation for my thesis defense and I would like to download the file to avoid any possible issues with Overleaf or my internet connection during my presentation.

The issue is I have a lot of transitions in my presentation and the only option I seem to have in Overleaf to download offline is to download a PDF. When I download the PDF it does not maintain any of my transitions and there is no capability to "click through" the presentation.

What is the best way to download a Beamer presentation for offline use with full functionality?

Comment: Note that Overleaf is just an editor and your code is compiled using a recent TeX installation on some server. The output is therefore the same as you would get with any compilation via any TeX installation and it is typically a PDF. I don’t know much about Overleaf‘s PDF viewer. From what you describe it seems that it can handle transitions as can Acrobat Reader. But not all PDF viewers can handle transitions properly.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to this. The PDF exporter in Overleaf includes the presentation functionality. By opening the PDF in Adobe PDF and switching to full screen mode, the right arrow button can be used to transition through the package and will include all in-slide transitions